# Mössbauer effect literature's value resource

Tags: resource-recommendations, spectroscopy

I am doing [Mössbauer spectoscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_spectroscopy) at room temperature on the following materials:

1. Enriched iron
2. sodium nitroprusside
3. ferric sulfate

by using the source as $^{57}Co$. So far the experiment go pretty nice but I want to compare my values to the literature's one and I am having seriously difficult to find those online. I was wondering if anyone have a name of a book or paper that I can compare my values with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need exactly.

I personally like the tables at the end of this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b86125. It is intended more for synchrotron based Mössbauer spectroscopy, but it has a lot of tabulated nuclear resonance data.

For a review on Mössbauer spectroscopy as a whole see this recent book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-15-9422-9. Depending on the community, there are also various citations for data sources in the literature chain there.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the first book you linked is not available in my institution. I mainly looking for comparing the isomer shift, quadropole spliting and zeeman spliting. I would like if you can help me find alternative source

Comment: @Sagigever It would probably be helpful to know more about what exactly you are looking for. (e.g.: Bare nuclear resonance data? - For your experiment (57Fe) you can find those on wikipedia. Time spectra calculations? - There are software packages for that.)